# jQuery DataTable settings re-initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a jQuery dataTable Version 1.7.6.
I am showing a dataTable on a dialog box., with normal 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons on it.
At run time, I apply sort on different columns or change the Number of rows to display and hit Cancel to close the dialog. I am not able to refresh the dataTable settings the next time it pops up on the dialog box. The previous actions I performed still persist. i.e. the 'iDisplayLength' remains the same that i had selected before closing, or the column sorted still remains the same.

I tried **oTable.fnDraw()** and **oTable.fnClearTable()**.
But, it does not reset the dataTable parameters to the init values.

Am I missing something! Does fnDraw and fnClearTable only clear/reset the data in the table and not the settings?

I guess the position I initialize my dataTable plays some role in the same. I have initialized the dataTable in the $(function() {}); of my JavaScript.

Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this following:**

```
if(oTable != null)oTable.fnDestroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

if dataTable already init means that table length should be greater than zero .if not table length should be Zero.try this it all seems to work.

```
if(oTable.length>0)
  oTable.fnDestroy();
```